# Data acquisition of AWS IoT Aanalytics

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-iot-analytics

I would like to obtain the latest data by specifying Lambda's IoT Analytics dataset.

If you use getDatasetContent of IoTAnalytics of aws sdk, only the link for downloading the file will be returned.
Data itself can not be acquired.

I would like to know how to obtain information on the IoT Analytics data set from Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to get the data from an IoT Analytics Dataset using a Lambda function?

You are correct that get_dataset_content only returns the URI, but it is simple to then fetch the actual content, for example in Python it would look like this;

```
# Code Fragment to retrieve content from IoT Analytics Dataset

iota = boto3.client('iotanalytics')  
response = iota.get_dataset_content(datasetName='my_data_set',versionId='$LATEST')
contentState = response['status']['state']

if (contentState == 'SUCCEEDED') :
    url = response['entries'][0]['dataURI']
    stream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    reader = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(stream, 'utf-8'))

    for record in reader:
        # Process the record as desired, you can refer to columns in the CSV
        # by using record['column_name'] using the DictReader iterator
```

Note that this code is specifically looking at the most recent results using the $LATEST version - you can also look for the $LATEST_SUCCEEDED version.

There's more [documentation here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iotanalytics.html#client) for Boto - the AWS Python SDK, but you can use the same approach in all other sdk supported languages.

Hope that helps,
Roger